# Commpering data from MongoDB in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, protractor, cucumber

First of all, coding is new thing for me. Until now I was manual tester in Java applications.
Now, my task is learn to do "automate stuff" and I'm stuck on one problem.

I'm trying get data from MongoDB and compare it with test data. Test is a mix of Protractor and Cucumber.

I think problem is in something I don't understand or I don't know yet.

In mongoDB I have:

```
{
    "_id" : 123456,
    "mykey" : 2
}
```

Code in IDE:

```
import * as chai from 'chai';
import * as chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const expect = chai.expect;

module.exports = function () {
    this.Then(/^Data should be same$/, function (callback) {

// Connection to mongoDB

    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:8517/fpl').then(function(db) {

      const collection = db.collection('test');

// Test data

      const testData = [{
        _id: 123456,
        mykey: 2
      }];

// Query to DB for data

      const a = collection.find({_id: 123456}).toArray();

// "is data from DB == test data?"

      return expect(a).to.eventually.equal(testData).notify(callback);


    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
});
```

As Result I got message:

```
Message:
 AssertionError: expected [ { _id: 123456, mykey: 2 } ] to equal [ { _id: 123456, mykey: 2 } ]

1 scenario (1 failed)
1 step (1 failed)
0m00.094s
AssertionError: expected [ { _id: 123456, mykey: 2 } ] to equal [ { _id: 123456, mykey: 2 } ]
  message: 'expected [ { _id: 123456, mykey: 2 } ] to equal [ { _id: 123456, mykey: 2 } ]',
  showDiff: true,
  actual: [ { _id: 123456, mykey: 2 } ],
  expected: [ { _id: 123456, mykey: 2 } ] }
[14:22:34] I/local - Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[14:22:34] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[14:22:34] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[14:22:34] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[14:22:34] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use `deep` flag
http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_deep

```
collection.find({_id: 123456}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    expect(docs).to.deep.equal(testData).notify(callback);
});
```

Comment: Updated, try now

Comment: Still error
    [15:34:48] E/launcher - [ { _id: 123456, mykey: 2 } ] is not a thenable.
    [15:34:48] E/launcher - TypeError: [ { _id: 123456, mykey: 2 } ] is not a thenable.

I think problem is type of data from db,

Comment: I forgot to change `eventually` to `deep`, sorry :)

Comment: I try "deep" after first error, still same "is not a thenable"